# Como puedo guardar el resultado de un ToggleSwitch en una variable

Tags: flutter, dart

//Deseo que el resultado se guarde en una variable para poderla almacenar en mi base de datos

```
    ToggleSwitch(
        initialLabelIndex: 0,
        totalSwitches: 2,
        labels: [
          'Si',
          'No',
        ],
        onToggle: (index) {
          print('switched to: $index');
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero,

Estás usando un package externo que te proporciona un componente que no es propio de Flutter, por tanto, deberías indicar el nombre del package.
https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch.

Además, ¿cuál es la pregunta? ¿Cómo acceder a los valores o cómo almacenarlos en la base de datos? ¿O ambas? No queda claro.

Segundo, la solución:

```dart
final myValues = <String>['Sí', 'No'];

class MyWidgetExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidgetExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ToggleSwitch(
      initialLabelIndex: 0,
      totalSwitches: myValues.length,
      labels: myValues,
      onToggle: (index) {
        final value = myValues[index];
        // lógica para almacenar en la base de datos
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Explicación:
Para poder acceder a los valores a través del index, necesitas guardar los valores en una lista. El cómo le pases dicha lista, ya es cosa de cómo quieras implementarlo.

Comment: Si, quiero hacer ambas. Obtener los valores según la selección que se haya hecho de si o no y almacenarlos en una variable para asi guardarlos en mi base de datos que seria en Firebase data base

Comment: En ese caso, estás haciendo más de una pregunta, lo cual va en contra de las normas. Te recomendaría que edites tu pregunta para hacer solo una. Si me respuesta te ha servido, podrías marcarla como la correcta, para ayudar a otras personas que puedan tener tu misma duda. Además, te alentaría a intentar resolver el problema para poder exponer el código de lo que has intentando. Por otra parte, no indicas nada sobre la base de datos que estás usando ni cuál es el problema a la hora de guardar los datos.

Comment: No, tu respuesta  no me ayudo a solucionarlo y gracias por las recomendaciones es la primera vez que utilizo esta plataforma para hacer una pregunta.